# How can I manage error code SQL in MS access form database?

Tags: sql, sql-server, ms-access, duplicates

I want manage SQL server error code in access form
sample duplicate error from SQL server

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In Access VBA, you need to use:

```
On Error GoTo Error_Handler
' YOUR CODE HERE
.
.
.
Return_Label:
Exit Function

Error_Handler:
'What goes here depends on the data access model
Resume Return_Label
```

Answer (score 0):

You may have to retrieve the *Errors* collection of the *Error* object as described [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff835711.aspx).

It shows this example code:

```
Sub DescriptionX() 

   Dim dbsTest As Database 

   On Error GoTo ErrorHandler 

   ' Intentionally trigger an error. 
   Set dbsTest = OpenDatabase("NoDatabase") 

   Exit Sub 

ErrorHandler: 
   Dim strError As String 
   Dim errLoop As Error 

   ' Enumerate Errors collection and display properties of  
   ' each Error object. 
   For Each errLoop In Errors 
      With errLoop 
         strError = _ 
            "Error #" & .Number & vbCr 
         strError = strError & _ 
            "  " & .Description & vbCr 
         strError = strError & _ 
            "  (Source: " & .Source & ")" & vbCr 
         strError = strError & _ 
            "Press F1 to see topic " & .HelpContext & vbCr 
         strError = strError & _ 
            "  in the file " & .HelpFile & "." 
      End With 
      MsgBox strError 
   Next 

   Resume Next 

End Sub
```

Comment: While this accounts for the _handling the error in VBA_ part, this error isn't caused by a VBA sub or function, thus the answer is not applicable. The hard part (well, harder but still not that hard) is making sure you handle the update in VBA on a bound datasheet form, enabling you to trap the error.

Comment: But @ErikvonAsmuth, Mostafa seems to use a bound form and has probably adapted the code.

Comment: Yes, but for future users, you should include that part in my opinion. If the only challenge would be "how to do error handling in VBA", it would be more appropriate to mark this question as a duplicate