# SQL error on ms access database form

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I have an access database connected to SQL Server.

How can I change the display of the error generated by SQL server in my database access form?

example:
**SQL Server error in access form:**

ODBC - call failed.

> [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server] The UPDATE statement  connficted with the FOREGIN KEY constraint "FK_Student_id". The conflict occured in database "myDatabase", table "dbo.student", column 'Date'.(#547)
>
> [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server] the statement has been terminated. (#3621)

I want change it to this Message :

*Access:*
**msgbox"You cannot change this record because ..."**

[image: SQL Server error in access form]

Comment: Make sure the update field's data is PK or FK,and Is PK value duplicate on another row.

Comment: 1) Get error number (`Err.Number`). 2) Use that error number in `If`: `If Err.Number = ...`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Disable default msgbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14957869/disable-default-msgbox)

Comment: ^^ this is how you catch the error, and this is how to handle it: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47174941/3820271